# Binomial random effects model with disaggregated covariates

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, modeling

I have an numerator and denominator data for an outcome variable from multiple countries disaggregated by several factors, such as age and gender - similar to:

| country | gender | age | denominator | numerator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country A | M | <=15 | 1414 | 958 |
| Country A | M | >15 | 1462 | 837 |
| Country A | F | <=15 | 1178 | 121 |
| Country A | F | >15 | 1525 | 1372 |
| Country B | M | <=15 | 1194 | 293 |
| Country B | M | >15 | 1937 | 81 |
| Country B | F | <=15 | 1817 | 595 |
| Country B | F | >15 | 1117 | 1066 |
| Country C | M | <=15 | 1298 | 1154 |
| Country C | M | >15 | 1228 | 850 |
| Country C | F | <=15 | 1243 | 796 |
| Country C | F | >15 | 1013 | 1007 |

Let's say I would like to examine the question, *is gender associated with the outcome*, while taking into account heterogeneity between countries.

**Would a binomial model with a random intercept for country be an appropriate analytical approach?** In this example, I would only be interested in the coefficient of the fixed effect for gender.

I'm a bit thrown off by the grouped categorical data, and not sure if there are statistical caveats associated with this type of data structure. In R, the proposed model would be:

```
lme4::glmer(cbind(denominator, numerator) ~ gender + (1 | country),
            data = df,
            family = binomial())
```

---

(example data)

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(country = rep(paste0("Country ", LETTERS[1:3]), each = 4),
                 gender = as.factor(rep(c("M", "M", "F", "F"), times = 3)),
                 age = as.factor(rep(c("<=15", ">15"), times = 6)),
                 denominator = sample(1000:2000, 12))
df$numerator <- floor(df$denominator * runif(12))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a fairly standard case: I'm not 100% clear on what's worrying you. I guess you're more used to a disaggregated format where the response variable was binary, with many observations for each country/gender/age combination?

The aggregated data are actually IMO better than the disaggregated data because of (1) computational efficiency (many fewer individual log-likelihoods to calculate!) and (2) possibility of testing for/accounting for overdispersion, e.g. see Hilbe, Joseph M. 2013. [“Can Binary Logistic Models Be Overdispersed?”](http://www.highstat.com/Books/BGS/GLMGLMM/pdfs/HILBE-Can_binary_logistic_models_be_overdispersed2Jul2013.pdf).

The *maximal model* for this case would be

```r
cbind(denominator, numerator) ~ gender*age + (1 + gender*age | country)
```

This model may be too complex for your data (singular fits, blah blah), but you should probably include at least the variation in gender effect across countries (i.e. `(1+gender|country)` if you are going to test the population-level effect of gender, e.g. see Schielzeth and Forstmeier 2009.

To simplify the process of testing the main effect of gender, you should probably specify sum-to-zero contrasts (`contrasts = list(gender = contr.sum, age = contr.sum)`, or globally via `options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))`

---

Schielzeth, Holger, and Wolfgang Forstmeier. 2009. “Conclusions beyond Support: Overconfident Estimates in Mixed Models.” Behavioral Ecology 20 (2): 416–20. https://doi.org/10.1093/beheco/arn145.

Comment: Thanks you so much, Ben - this is what I assumed, but never rely on *my* assumptions (essentially I'm "statistics-as-a-second-language", so wanted to confirm this with a native speaker). I also didn't know about the global contrasts. Thanks again!